# how to select all table records except last 2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I am using Yii, I want to select all records of a model except the last 2 records, but I got an error that there is syntax error, here is my code:

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->select = "*";
$c->condition = "idNewsEvents!=(SELECT MAX(idNewsEvents) FROM newsevents) AND idNewsEvents!=(SELECT MAX(idNewsEvents)-1 FROM newsevents))";
$model2 = Newsevents::model()->findAll($c);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one considers, that idNewsEvents might not be sequential (due to deletes or whatever).

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->select = "*";
$c->condition = "idNewsEvents NOT IN (SELECT idNewsEvents FROM newsevents ORDER BY idNewsEvents DESC LIMIT 2)";
$model2 = Newsevents::model()->findAll($c);
```

P.S.: Not sure if this is correct yii syntax, I'm not familiar with it, but I'm very familiar with MySQL. Anyway, you get the idea I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Two checking can be done in a single checking

```
$c->condition ="idNewsEvents < (SELECT MAX(idNewsEvents)-1 FROM newsevents)";
```

**Example query**

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id < (SELECT MAX(user_id)-1 FROM users)
```

Comment: What if the id is not strictly sequential?

Comment: @fancyPants His condition is also produce the same result,i think

Answer (score -2):

it should be:

```
$c->condition = "idNewsEvents!=(SELECT MAX(idNewsEvents)
FROM newsevents) AND idNewsEvents!=(SELECT MAX(idNewsEvents)-1 FROM newsevents)";
```

There were just an extra bracket at end and a very tired eyes to notice that :( .

Comment: Should this be an answer or an edit to your question? And have you considered, that the news events ID might not be strictly sequential?

Comment: its an answer not additional information.